# Storing functions & subs for global use?

Tags: asp.net

what is the best way to store functions and sub routines so that every page in my site can use them?

At the moment they are on one aspx.vb page and I would need to copy them to each page I want to use them on, I really don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using VB.NET, you can use a Module in the App_Code folder to store functions.

If you are using C#, you can create a class with static functions

VB.NET:

```
Public Module Utilities

    Public Function MyFuct()

    End Function

End Module
```

C#:

```
public class Utilities
{

    static public string MyFuct()
    {

    }
}
```

Then, call using:

```
Utilities.MyFuct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what the classes do, I would categorize them into classes, or helper-type static classes. Again, it just depends on what you need them for.